# How did Tepei draw his Livlaster without anyone noticing?

Tags: captain-earth

The summoning of a Livlaster has a distinct light effect. It is shown that even behind cover, you can see the glare.

Then at the fighting ring, Teppei is without the Livlaster when entering, but after Amara's entrance, Tepei is chastised by Daichi to hide it and "this is not the place to use that" stuff.

How could he summon the Livlaster (offscreen) without anyone in the audience noticing?

Comment: Well, realistically, it can be explained by "everyone is paying attention to the star on the ring and normally there is no reason to bother looking behind them". Or in tropes' term, http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PerceptionFilter